# How do I make my rewrite rule in my .htaccess file?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

I have a path of /posts/Bob/53c6acf8963e3/

Where posts relates to a file called post.php.
Bob is a username and 53c6acf8963e3 is a unique string.

so it should relate to something like post.php?username=bob&unique_string=53c6acf8963e3
But I don't want to use that as it doesn't look nice aha.

What htaccess rule could I use?

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Comment: Please include what you have tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: @showdev well I haven't tried anything because I'm clueless with .htaccess rules and "what goes wrong", well I have explained what I need in order to achieve my desired result so I have no idea what you're on about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w]+)/([\w]+)/?$             $1.php?username=$2&unique_string=$3 [QSA,L]
```

See more on [QSA flag here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$   $1.php?username=$2&unique_string=$3  [NC,L]
```